# Two indexes with same name in Oracle schema

Tags: oracle, indexing

I'm wondering why can't I have two indexes with same name in Oracle schema? It throws an error  saying that the name is already been used.
I was under an impression, since the index is on a particular table, this should not cause any error unless we use same index name for two different columns on the same table.

Any explanation is most helpful.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: All oracle indexes share the same namespace (http://mehrajdba.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/namespaces/) and are not automatically based on the table name they are created on. When you name indexes you can certainly prefix the name of the target table on to the index. You'd end up with `Table1_Index1` but you have to enforce that by convention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `CREATE INDEX index_name ...`, you're creating index object in your schema, and each object must have an unique name.

Answer (score 0):

It helps with error messages and so forth that index names are unique,  In any case it is what it is.